# In a JSF custom component, is there any way to ensure that an attribute contains a correct value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

For example, let's say that I have a component with an attribute called `percent`. This attribute must be an integer from `0-100`, otherwise it makes no sense.

If the developer specifies:

```
<my:component percent="101" />
```

Is there any sort of attribute validation available to detect the error and notify the developer of it in JSF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this (which admittedly feels a little hacky), is to check if the attribute has a valid value in the renderer and throw an `IOException` if the value isn't valid.